# JNI(Java) equivalent of INCREF, DECREF used in python embed for C++?

Tags: java, c++, python, java-native-interface

What is the JNI(Java) equivalent of INCREF, DECREF which is used in 
python embed for C++?

Or is there no equivalent? 
Any reason why there isn't any equivalent?

Comment: [Reference Counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's garbage collection model is different: while Python uses reference-counting as its main garbage collector method, Java doesn't.

Java uses what is called "tracing" garbage collectors: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Tracing_garbage_collectors).

With this in mind, the closest equivalents to `INCREF` and `DECREF` are probably `NewGlobalRef` and `DeleteGlobalRef`.

See [Chapter 5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html) of the JNI manual.

Comment: Since Java doesnt use reference counting, What model does Java use for garbage collection then?

Comment: @seahorse: See "tracing garbage collectors" in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Tracing_garbage_collectors

Comment: Thanks for explaining the distinction!